# starting wso2server.bat hangs on Activating org.wso2.jaggery.scxml with RealmService enabled

Tags: java, wso2

I am starting the `wso2server.bat --run`.  I get to Activating org.wso2.jaggery.scxml with RealmService enabled and never gets beyond that. There are no error in the log. How can I debug and fix this problem?

Comment: Can you give us more information on the problem, and how to reproduce it? What have you tried so far? More information about the WSO2 server you're using in also needed!

Comment: more information?  I think my instruction describe the problem and how to re-produce it.

Comment: Okay, let's see if someone can help you then...